# Framework for creating business objects used in a C# web application

Tags: c#, frameworks

Can anyone recommend a framework.  We are looking at Strata Frame but it doesn't seem to work real well with a web application.

Answer (score 1):

Rocky Lhotka's [CSLA framework](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/Default.aspx#) is widely used and praised as a great way to start your business objects.

It's available for .NET, Silverlight, and Windows CE.

This is really just a business-objects oriented framework - everything else is still up for you to decide and implement.

Strata Frame seems to be much more than just that - it's a complete app framework - if that's what you're looking for, I have heard good things about (but never used it myself) [IronSpeed Designer](http://www.ironspeed.com).

**UPDATE:** as for resources - well, there's Rocky's site as the primary source, and I'm sure if you google for it, you'll find tons of blog posts on the topic.

Also, there's a two-part Dotnet Rocks TV Screencast with Rocky himself on the topic:

- [Rocky Lhotka on CSLA .NET 3.5 Part 1](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=116)
- [Rocky Lhotka on CSLA .NET 3.5 Part 2](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=120)

Comment: It appears you have to buy the books from CSLA to learn it.  It there an online reference/documentation site.

Answer (score 0):

What's the requirement for "business objects"? I think CSLA has the most grown-up business objects so far, but if you are just thinking about the domain objects you could also consider [s#arp architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/default.aspx), which is using ASP.NET MVC in the front and NHibernate in the back and provides you with a nice infrastructure framework out of the box. Didn't use it so far in productive environment, bt definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quicker way to learn CSLA and a great compliment to the CSLA books. We have a set of [CSLA 3.8 templates](http://code.google.com/p/codesmith/downloads/list) that cover many of the nooks of CSLA that takes ages to find out on your own. They come in both a VB.NET and a C# flavor. We are currently working on a major release that adds SQL Stored Procedure, Object Factory and Many-to-Many support. It is a great starting point because we have real world examples like the Microsoft PetShop Sample application that is completely generated (both the business layers and data access layers ) with unit tests to show you exactly how CSLA works. If you have any questions or run into issues we are here to help you understand and grow as a CSLA developer.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))